# pass zip file from unc to python code running inside docker

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have a python script running inside a docker container. This app does the loading of builds on to external hardware which is connected on the network. The builds are in zip format and are available in the local network share \\path\to\zip.zip. I am running a python script inside the docker container to trigger this loading zip file.

The python script is simple. All it takes is >python load.py IP path_to_zip

The script then unzips the contents and makes an ftp connection to the hardware and erases the existing contents, then loads the contents of the zip file.

At the moment, I see that the docker container is not able to access the unc path. The script runs fine on a normal environment (without docker)

I've tried it in different ways to resolve the issue

1. 1.When I try giving the unc path from inside docker (attaching shell), I see that it cannot find the unc path
2. I tried building the Docker container with the zip file in it so that it is available. But I do not see the contents getting uploaded
   to the hardware. I am not sure why.

can someone suggest what is the best way to perform point 1? which is my preferred option...

Comment: What is the `unc` path? Where will the files be extracted to? into the container or host machine?

Comment: unc path is a windows share. The contents will be extracted to the host machine

Comment: I guess you need to take a look at using `docker volumes` section. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/